# How to make python output a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation

I am trying to build the Tolk library (https://github.com/dkager/tolk), but I run into troubles.

I executed following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/dkager/tolk && cd tolk
build_tolk_x64
build_python
```

but I get the following error:

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

When I go look in the src/python directory, there only is a subdirectory called **pycache** and the original Tolk.py file; the same for bin. It looks like py_compile didn't create the file at all, or it deleted it immediately after creation.

When I tried

```
python -O -m py_compile src/python/Tolk.py
```

the system didn't create a file either. I started looking for a solution on the internet, but I couldn't find something like this. A lot of articles, tutorials and questions about the normal creation, but not really a problem like this.
Can somebody here give me some advice where to look or how I could make things work like you would expect?

Comment: https://github.com/dkager/tolk#compiling

Comment: @bruno I followed that and I have all that installed. It just does not work...

Comment: Then please edit your post to add this information.

Comment: in python3, compiled byte-code file should under `src/python/__pycache__/`, besides py3 do not have `.pyo` file, so `build_python.bat` wont work, i guess this lib only works with python2.

Comment: @georgexsh So I need to use the main .py file, if I want to try if the application works with Python 3?

Comment: I guess you could use `Tolk.py` directly, the byte-code file is nothing more than a mean to speed up.

Comment: @bruno I thought it would be clear, since I used the commands and that I have the needed softwareavailable. Besides, the missing file does not accord to the software which has to be installed, otherwise I wouldn't be able to run the build commands, nor other python scripts or Java classes or create Java classes... Thanks though.

Comment: @JordyDeweer never assume something "would be clear" for the reader. I at least took time to quickly browse the project's git, most readers won't even bother. IOW if you hope to get a useful answer you have to include absolutely ALL relevant informations in your question. For example, you do not mention which of the commands you ran outputed this error message.

Comment: Also and fwiw, you don't need a precompiled version of the Tolk.py file, the python runtime can use the source file just as well, so I'm not sure your problem has anything to do with python.

Comment: @Bruno Thank you very much for the tips. StackOverflow is a quite new thing for me... and I never god such feedback.